# How to view the rendered html in Jasmine and Karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Brand new to AngularJS - and I was watching a video tutorial when I noticed that the html of the component being tested was showing inside the Jasmine interface.

My project does not show the html inside the Jasmine interface - just the list of the tests. I was wondering how can Jasmine or Karma be configured to do that? Seems like a useful feature.

Comment: Read this whole article especially the section on `Inspect the DOM`: https://testing-angular.com/debugging-tests/#debugging-tests.

Comment: @AliF50 Thank you for the link. Inspecting the elements - seems like the the actual html is under an `iframe` with `#document` with a link to it but I can't view it.

Comment: `component` tests should have the HTML. Try with a dummy component that has `<p>Hello world</p>`.